# parse a csv file into a text file

Tags: python, c, parsing, csv, find-all-references

I am a second year EE student.
I just started learning python for my project.

I intend to parse a csv file with a format like

```
3520005,"Toronto (Ont.)",C ,F,2503281,2481494,F,F,0.9,1040597,979330,630.1763,3972.4,1
2466023,"Montréal (Que.)",V ,F,1620693,1583590,T,F,2.3,787060,743204,365.1303,4438.7,2
5915022,"Vancouver (B.C.)",CY ,F,578041,545671,F,F,5.9,273804,253212,114.7133,5039.0,8
3519038,"Richmond Hill (Ont.)",T ,F,162704,132030,F,F,23.2,53028,51000,100.8917,1612.7,28
```

into a text file like the following

Toronto 2503281
Montreal 1620693
Vancouver 578041

I am extracting the 1st and 5th column and save it into a text file.

This is what i have so far.

```
import csv
file = open('raw.csv')
reader = csv.reader(file)

f = open('NicelyDone.text','w')

for line in reader:
      f.write("%s %s"%line[1],%line[5])
```

This is not working for me, I was able to extract the data from the csv file as line[1],line[5]. (I am able to print it out)
But I dont know how to write it to a .text file in the format i wanted.

Also, I have to process the first column eg, "Toronto (Ont.)" into "Toronto".
I am familiar with the function find(), I assume that i could extract Toronto out of Toronto(Ont.) using "(" as the stopping character, 
but based on my research , I have no idea how to use it and ask it to return me the string(Toronto).

Here is my question:

1. What is the data format for `line[1]`?

   - If it is string how come `f.write()` does not work?
   - If it is not string, how do i convert it to a string?
2. How do i extract the word `Toronto` out of `Toronto(Ont)` into a string form using `find()` or other methods.

My thinking is that I could add those 2 string together like `c = a+ ' ' + b`, that would give me the format i wanted.
So i can use `f.write()` to write into a file   :)

Sorry if my questions sounds too easy or stupid.

Thanks ahead

Zhen

Answer (score 1):

1. All data read you get from `csv.reader` are strings.
2. There is a variety of solutions to this, but the simplest would be to split on `(` and strip away any whitespace:

   ```
   >>> a = 'Toronto (Ont.)'
   >>> b = a.split('(')
   >>> b
   Out[16]: ['Toronto ', 'Ont.)']
   >>> c = b[0]
   >>> c
   Out[18]: 'Toronto '
   >>> c.strip()
   Out[19]: 'Toronto'
   ```

   or in one line:

   ```
   >>> print 'Toronto (Ont.)'.split('(')[0].strip()
   ```

   Another option would have been to use regular expression (the [re module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)).

The specific problem in your code lies here:

```
f.write("%s %s"%line[1],%line[5])
```

Using the `%` syntax to format your string, you have to provide either a single value, or an iterable. In your case this should be:

```
f.write("%s %s" % (line[1], line[5]))
```

Another way to do the exact same thing, is to use the [`format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method.

```
f.write('{} {}'.format(line[1], line[5]))
```

This is a flexible way of formating strings, and I recommend that you read about in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

---

Regarding your code, there is a couple of things you should consider.

- Always remember to close your file handlers. If you use `with open(...) as fp`, this is taken care of for you.

  ```
  with open('myfile.txt') as ifile:
      # Do stuff
  # The file is closed here
  ```
- Don't use reserved words as your variable name. `file` is such a thing, and by using it as something else (*shadowing* it), you may cause problems later on in your code.
- To write your data, you can use [csv.writer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer):

  ```
  with open('myfile.txt', 'wb') as ofile:
      writer = csv.writer(ofile)
      writer.writerow(['my', 'data'])
  ```
- From Python 2.6 and above, you can combine multiple `with` statements in one statement:

  ```
  with open('raw.csv') as ifile, open('NicelyDone.text','w') as ofile:
      reader = csv.reader(ifile)
      writer = csv.writer(ofile)
  ```

Combining this knowledge, your script can be rewritten to something like:

```
import csv

with open('raw.csv') as ifile, open('NicelyDone.text', 'wb') as ofile:
    reader = csv.reader(ifile)
    writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in reader:
        city, num = row[1].split('(')[0].strip(), row[5]
        writer.writerow([city, num])
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't recall `csv` that well, so I don't know if it's a string or not. What error are you getting? In any case, assuming it *is* a string, your line should be:

   ```
   f.write("%s %s " % (line[1], line[5]))
   ```

   In other words, you need a set of parentheses. Also, you should have a trailing space in   your string.
2. A somewhat hackish but concise way to do this is: `line[1].split("(")[0]`

   This will create a list that splits on the `(` symbol, and then you extract the first element.